# Need to embed `-` character into arguments in python argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, command-line-interface, argparse

I am designing a tool to meet some spec. I have a scenario where I want the argument to contain `-` its string. Pay attention to `arg-1` in the below line.

```
python test.py --arg-1 arg1Data
```

I am using the `argparse` library on `python27`. For some reason the argparse gets confused with the above trial.

My question is how to avoid this? How can I keep the `-` in my argument?

A sample program (containing the `-`, if this is removed everything works fine):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--arg-1", help="increase output verbosity")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.args-1:
   print "verbosity turned on"
```

Comment: Python interprets `args.args-1` as `args.args - 1`, subtraction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python argparse module replace dashes by underscores, thus:

```
if args.arg_1:  
    print "verbosity turned on"
```

Python doc (second paragraph of section [15.4.3.11. dest](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#dest)) states:

> Any internal `-` characters will be converted to `_` characters to make
>   sure the string is a valid attribute name.

Comment: @sudhishkr `--arg-1` is a boolen value (store_true) it means it is TRUE when it is passed in command line and FALSE when it is not in command line argument. That is how it works. Boolean args cannot have values

Comment: My bad  on that one. I actually realised it after posing the comment. I removed mine, and looks like you responded immediately. I am taking your approach, but will be selecting Dan.D's answer as the right one for this Q as it will work for any special characters. Thanks @felipsmartins

Answer (score 1):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--arg-1", help="increase output verbosity")
parser.add_argument("arg-2")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

produces:

```
1750:~/mypy$ python stack34970533.py -h
usage: stack34970533.py [-h] [--arg-1 ARG_1] arg-2

positional arguments:
  arg-2

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --arg-1 ARG_1  increase output verbosity
```

and

```
1751:~/mypy$ python stack34970533.py --arg-1 xxx yyy
Namespace(arg-2='yyy', arg_1='xxx')
```

The first argument is an `optional`.  You can use '--arg-1' in commandline, but the value is stored as `args.arg_1`.  Python would interpret `args.arg-1` as `args.arg - 1`.  There's a long history of unix commandlines allowing flags with a `-`.  It tries to balance both traditions.

It leaves you in full control of the `positionals` `dest` attribute, and does not change the `-` to `_`.  If you want to access that you have to use the `getattr` approach.  There is bug/issue discussing whether this behavior should be changed or not.  But for now, if you want to make it hard on yourself, that's your business.

Internally, `argparse` accesses the `namespace` with `getattr` and `setattr` to minimize restrictions on the attribute names.